# Use TiKZ-graphdrawing with overlay specifications of beamer

Tags: beamer, overlays, tikz-graphdrawing

I would like to progressively develop a graph created with during a beamer presentation. Here is a MWE:

```tex
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{graphs, graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{layered}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \graph[layered layout]
        {%
            "1" -- {"2", "3"},

            {"2", "3"}  -- "4",
            % \only<2->{{"2", "3"}  -- "4",}
            {"2", "3"} -- "5",
            % \only<3->{{"2", "3"} -- "5",}

            {"4", "5"} -- "6",
            % \only<4->{{"4", "5"} -- "6",}

        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The commented lines show my intent but they lead to errors.

Ty for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the `overlay-beamer-styles` library:

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{graphs, graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{layered}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \graph[layered layout]
        {%
            "1" -- {"2", "3"},

            {"2", "3"} -- [draw on=<2->] "\alt<2->{4}{\phantom{4}}",
            
            {"2", "3"} -- [draw on=<3->] "\alt<3->{5}{\phantom{5}}",
            
            {"\alt<2->{4}{\phantom{4}}", "\alt<3->{5}{\phantom{5}}"} -- [draw on=<4->] "\alt<4->{6}{\phantom{6}}",

        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What about `{"2", "3"} -- [draw on=<2->] "4" [visible on=<2->]`? Then you can just keep the original node references.

Comment: @JasperHabicht This gives a "funny" layout if used for the whole graph

Comment: Does it? I get a nice result without any shifting. In the end `visible on` only sets the opacity.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Ah, sorry, I must have made some error when testing.

Comment: @JasperHabicht I'm looking forward to read your answer!

Answer (score 4):

samcarter already introduced the nice idea of using the `overlay-beamer-styles` library.

An alternative approach to their use of the `\alt` macro would be to use the `visible on` option provided by this library. It essentially sets the options `opacity` and `text opacity` to zero, which means that you won't get any layout shifts and you can even keep the node names. You would need to apply this option both to the edges and the nodes.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs, graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{layered}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \graph[layered layout]
        {%
            "1" -- {"2", "3"},
            
            {"2", "3"} -- [visible on=<2->] "4" [visible on=<2->],

            {"2", "3"} -- [visible on=<3->] "5" [visible on=<3->],

            {"4", "5"} -- [visible on=<4->] "6" [visible on=<4->],
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]